# Sql query data filter between two table

Tags: mysql

```
Table1        
ID  Name            
L2  abc        
L3  xyz          
L4  pqr          
L5  ghi

Table 2    
ID code
L4 1
L3 2
L4 4
L2 3
L4 1
```

In the above table, I want to output where I received all Id's with name and code, except for the id L4, which should not contain code 4.

Comment: And what have you tried so far ? Also, go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first

Answer (score 0):

You can use join and where condition

```
select a.id,a.name, b.code 
from table1 a left join table2 b on a.id=b.id
and exists (select 1 from table2 c where a.id=c.id and c.code<>4 )
```

Comment: Thanks but i made addition in the question can you please help me now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
select t1.id, t1.name, t2.code 
    from table1 t1 
    inner join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
    where (t2.id != 'L4' or t2.code != 4)
```